# Is there a way to use ibm_db on python 2.7 64-bit on windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, db2

I installed python 2.7 32-bit version and I am able to run `pip install ibm_db` (current version is 2.0.8), and then call `import ibm_db` and everything works. When I use python 2.7 64-bit, however, the install via pip works fine, but when I try and `import ibm_db` I get the following error:

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ibm_db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 10, in <module>
    __bootstrap__()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 9, in __bootstrap__
    imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>>>
```

The DLL in question is `<site-packages>/ibm_db_dlls/ibm_db.dll`, and its there, but when I open it using Dependency Walker, it seems to be the 32 bit version.

Anybody know if there is a 64 bit compatible ibm_db.dll, or a way to make this work? I need this to run in an environment (windows server) with 64 bit python, and I don't have control over the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting previous comment to answer.

I run Python 2.7.14 (64-bit) with ibm_db (2.0.8) on 64-bit Windows 8.1 workstation, with a 64-bit Db2 V11.1 client.

I have no issues with the above combination of 64-bit components.

If the 64-bit combination runs OK on the workstation, I don't see why it would not also run on Windows-Server, if properly configured.

Could your Windows-server have some mashup of 32-bit and 64-bit artefacts for Python and/or ibm_db ?  Or some incorrect PATH settings etc?

Note: I used easy_install to deliver the ibm_db (following IBM's instructions in Db2 knowledge center).

Comment: Thank you! I got this working using easy_install. I had assumed pip would do basically the same thing, but via easy_install the setup.py will actually detect the OS arch and download the correct db2 ODBC drivers.

Comment: Another note, since I want to do an offline install of all dependencies using pip, I first installed the .egg using easy_install, then used `wheel convert` to turn that into a .whl so I can install using pip from a requirements file and a bunch of cached wheels. All works now.